# If I have 24 categories with sub-categories in my shop page, where would be the best place for them?

Tags: website-design, design-patterns, e-commerce, responsive-design, categorization

The design is specifically to Desktop, on Mobile and Tablet I'm planning to have a drawer window with the list of categories and its sub-categories. The idea is to make the category visible in the eye of the customers and make it less-hustle to access.

So in Desktop, I want it for the customer to become visible.

A sample of my current idea:

[image]

But I have a doubt about my design. I have a feeling that the customers may still not be able to see it unless they look or try to find it, another thing is I want it to be clean as much as possible to avoid confusion. It should be something, *"I'm looking for something, ahh right I just hover on these categories"*

I'm not really sure about my design so I'm gonna take a risk asking for some advice and alternative ideas.

Anyway, I'm limiting the sub-categories to have a second sub-category only, no more sub-categories after that.

```
PARENT CATEGORY
               -> SUB-CATEGORY
                              -> SUB-CATEGORY OF SUB-CATEGORY
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to show two different approaches from known companies.

1. [Nike](https://www.nike.com/)

[image: Nike - Landing Page]

In their landing page we can see the different categories in the top. Once the user hover on one of them we can see then the subcategories displayed.

[image: All categories displayed]

Please see that with one hover they are displaying all the sub subcategories. That's very good, from an user perspective, because they can see everything.

This approach is excellent for any e-commerce.

2. [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/)

This example shows us something different. The target is not the same as in fashion industry, so, more subcategories are present here.

They provide a limited scroll with a dashboard of options:

[image]

Or if you want to search for more products you can use the hamburger button and check the categories:

[image]

I am assuming that the first example will fit better your idea of *"I'm looking for something, ahh right I just hover on these categories"*

Good luck with your task,

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment, so I'm giving my thoughts as an answer here instead.

Agree with Lino that Nike and Amazon are good examples that show different ways of organising **24** categories on the website. I don't know a third type of design that you can consider at this moment. What you sketched is close to the Nike design.

If the website is meant to be more search friendly, i.e. the users likely already have an idea what they want to buy in mind and just coming in straight to the stuff, the Amazon method will be more useful (coupled with an effective search bar).

On the other hand, if the website mainly attracts users to **browse** through the product listing, then adopting the Nike approach is better - it gives an overview of what is available on the platform. In this case, the choice of words to label the categories must be carefully selected, be sure to localise the labels too.

Answer (score -2):

Amazon, nailed it with handling wider list of categories and still having an effective user journey on their website. Amazon will be a better example to help you design based on the end user's intent.

Also for the mobile version of this design you test it thoroughly using [LT Browser](https://www.lambdatest.com/lt-browser), which gives you complete analysis by comparing different designs on latest pre-set devices. The best part, you can test on local environment!